# Can I remove the "open in terminal" menu item from nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

As simple as that. Can I remove the menu item?

(I actually want it because it is broken when one launches a custom edit in gnome-terminal so I compiled the old extension from pre-16.04 days that used to work, but now I have two "open in terminal" menu items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In recent versions of Nautilus such as 3.14 (included with Ubuntu 15.04), the Open in Terminal command is part of the gnome-terminal package, which installs the libterminal-nautilus extension (at `/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libterminal-nautilus.so`).

It can be easily removed in terminal w/ sudo:

```
$ sudo mv -vi /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libterminal-nautilus.so{,.bak}
```

Afterwards you need to quit Nautilus to see the changes applied:

```
$ nautilus -q

(nautilus:16373): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:16373): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:16373): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:16373): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:16373): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

If Nautilus does not quit this way successfully (e.g. you see a time-out), you can command your operating system to kill it:

```
$ pkill -e nautilus
nautilus killed (pid 15962)
```

Afterwards you can restart Nautilus and is will show the entry removed.

Before:

[image: before: nautilus context-menu with "open in terminal" entry]

After:

[image: after: nautilus context-menu without "open in terminal" entry]

Refs:

- [Please remove nautilus-open-terminal package - Bug #1451166 reported by Adam Dingle in May 2015](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/+bug/1451166))

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Ubuntu 18.04, the Nautilus extension responsible for "Open in Terminal" context menu option is part of a separate package called `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal`. This package is not part of `gnome-terminal`'s required dependencies (it is only part of the recommends) and can therefore be safely removed by running:

```
sudo apt remove nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
```

> In case it's of anyone's interest, the extension file now resides at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libterminal-nautilus.so` instead of the old `/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libterminal-nautilus.so` location. I wouldn't recommend touching it considering it's managed by the package manager but I felt I should include this information for the answer's completeness.